# Python Checking the Value of an Element in an Array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

In my program, I generate two lists each with 10 integers: one through user input, and one through random selection. Then, using `numpy`, I convert one of the lists into a 2x5 array, and the other into a 5x2 array and take the outer product to arrive at a 5x5 array like this:

```
 [[ 1 1 1 1 1]
  [ 1 1 1 1 1]
  [ 1 1 0 1 1]
  [ 1 1 1 1 1]
  [ 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

I want to ask the user some questions about the array, for example, "What is the value in the center of the resulting array?" (which would be 0 in this case).

How can I have Python check the value of the integer at the center of the array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking elements in a matrix in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20088364/checking-elements-in-a-matrix-in-python)

Comment: @pez I like the way you describe your question - it is succinct an clear. Keep on going this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array is `arr`, `arr[2,2]` will return the 3rd value down and 3rd value across (because indexing starts with 0). [See the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-6a1bc005bd80e1b19f812e1e64e0d25d50f99fe2).

Answer (score 1):

If your array is a square array with odd dimensions you can do

```
x.ravel()[x.size/2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the you are asking for the center, i am assuming that your array is going to have odd dimensions. if that is the case you could use the following:

```
print arr[len(arr)/2][len(arr[1])/2]
```

this divides the number of rows and columbs by 2 which will give you the middle index.